# django-helpdesk email template

Tags: json, django-models, django-templates, email-templates

I'm new to Django, and need help with a question about email templates.

I'm using a Django-helpdesk apps and it's have a model name *Ticket*. Along with many other fields, I would like to add an extra field to it, that is, a field name `foo`. All database is updated, and when a user submitter a new ticket, an email is sent to the user with some info, i.e `submitter_email`, dates etc. Everything seems to be correct but the new field `foo` I've added is blank.

For example, in email templates we can retrieve a *ticket id* by calling in HTML field:

```
{{ ticket.ticket }}
```

you'll get Ticket number `1234`, or:

```
{{ ticket.submitter_email }}
```

If you want to retrieve a *submitter email*. But when I call:

```
{{ ticket.foo }}
```

the `foo` is blank.

To mention: Django-Helpdesk email templates using JSON, and south, and I've checked that south is migrated corectly after the field `foo` is added.

Do I missed something here? I'm very thankful for your help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I've found my answer. All you need is to add your field `foo` in the contex of the method `safe_template_context(ticket)` in the `lib.py`.